# Calling Kubernetes Spark Operator with Java api

Tags: java, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-operator

There are plenty of good examples creating Spark jobs using the Kubernetes Spark Operator and simply submitting a request like the following

```
kubectl apply -f spark-pi.yaml
```

Where the spark-pi.yaml can be found at the this [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/blob/master/examples/spark-pi.yaml)

Does anyone know the easiest way to submit a job like this with the Java K8s api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to look into [Fabric8 K8s client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) used by Apache Spark in K8s or the official [Java K8s client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java). With these libs you can submit the K8s resources using the code.

Comment: Thanks, I did find an [example](https://medium.com/@rohaan/handling-kubernetes-custom-resources-in-java-using-fabric8-kubernetes-client-249c4fe01d27) using the Fabric client. I wasn't able to find the same with the java client, but did figure it out. I used the CustomObjectsApi.createNamespacedCustomObject() method.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a Application to submit spark job to Kubernetes where all you need to pass is Config Map (key value pair for app)

you could find the same in [github](https://github.com/bkosaraju/utils) Under class `RunSparkJobInKube(jobConfiguration: Map[String,String])`

this might help help you provide an idea for your requirement.

though this is scala you can call inside java as normal method.

here in this app I have integrated with IAM (aws specific) in case if you are interested in security.

Answer (score 0):

I have generated the Spark operator Java client to submit the spark job to Kubernetes. I am sharing the Github URL of repository [client-java-spark-operator](https://github.com/mukhtiarahmed/client-java-spark-operator-models)